# npm doesn't work without sudo, get cannot find module error

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to run npm install through a bash script

Initially I got

```
env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

This error was only to be found during a bash script that was executed through a CI/CD pipeline.
To counter this I had to do this

```
sudo ln -sf /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node /usr/bin/env
```

What this has done is that whenever I run npm on the terminal, I get this error

```
module.js:557
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/ubuntu/node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:190:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:662:3
```

One thing that I've noted is that wherever I run npm, the the folder i.e */home/ubuntu/node* changes to that particular directory

For ex -

```
module.js:557
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/ubuntu/scripts/node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:190:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:662:3
```

Adding some additional info

```
which node
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.4.0/bin/node
which npm
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.4.0/bin/npm
```

Ubuntu version is 16.04.3 LTS

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Comment: `sudo ln -sf /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node /usr/bin/env` is very wrong. The reason for the second error is that you have overwritten the `env` binary to link to `node` and now you are essentially running `node node` which fails. You should restore the `env` binary somehow. I believe if `which node` works then `/usr/bin/env node` should work as well. In which context are you trying to run the bash script?

Comment: I restored env binary by reinstalling core-utils. 
I am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline, so during the git pull, a script runs a file that after git pull does an npm install, that's where I was getting the */usr/bin/env* node error